# Provided API key could not be found

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm attempting to test Watson pizzeria chat bot but I get error on npm start within windows command line. I am using CONVERSATION_IAM_APIKEY & URL. I have copied/ pasted both values from ibm watson service. The error message= 
Message: "errorMessage":"Provided API key could not be found"}. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this and it works for me. Please make sure you copy and pasted the key correctly. Can you change the API key (so others cannot see it) and post the contents of your .env file?

Comment: here is .env. 
# Rename this file to .env before running 'npm start'
WORKSPACE_ID=<5e0f38de-4fbc-40d4-8690-323057b48327>

# Watson Assistant authentication using username/password authentication
#CONVERSATION_USERNAME=<apikey>
#CONVERSATION_PASSWORD=<>

# Watson Assistant Authentication using IAM
CONVERSATION_IAM_APIKEY=<********************************************>
CONVERSATION_URL=<https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api>

Comment: You need to please remove the angle brackets "< and >" from the .env file for IAM CONVERSATION_IAM_APIKEY, URL,  and WORKSPACE_ID. These are a convention used for variables, and are not to be included.

Comment: Thank you! I received "assistant is ready" message. My  next question, can you guide me on remaining step(s) to launch the chat bot?

Answer (score 0):

If it's wanting a username:password format and you have an api key then the username is apikey and the password is the value of your apikey